# devise create user not working with json. It is saying email is blank when it is present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am using devise for both an api and a web app.  The web app works perfectly.  When I try to create a user with ajax, it does not work.  Here is the ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/users',
  data: JSON.stringify({user: {email: 'demouser@demo.com', password: 'password', password_confirmation: 'password'}}),
  dataType: "json",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
});
```

The following responsetext is returned:

```
"{"errors":{"email":["can't be blank"],"password":["can't be blank"]}}"
```

Here are the logs:

```
Started POST "/api/users" for ::1 at 2016-08-13 15:44:59 -0400
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
application controller
yolo 
Processing by RegistrationsController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"user"=>{"email"=>"demouser@demo.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "registration"=>{"user"=>{"email"=>"deafdssadfaamousera2129@demo.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}}}
IN CREATE
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 40ms (Views: 1.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)
```

Here are the routes:

```
devise_for :users
namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
   devise_for :users, controllers: {registrations: "registrations"}, :defaults => { :format => :json }
end
```

And I use a `skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token` so it shouldn't have anything to do with that.  How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

**This can help:**

Please just remove `JSON.stringify` and use `{user: {email: 'demouser@demo.com', password: 'password', password_confirmation: 'password'}}` only.

**OR**

The link below shows how to submit html form with json data format. This is WC3 standard. I think this solves your problem. Please follow the link given below.

https://darobin.github.io/formic/specs/json/

Comment: Thanks but I'm not trying to submit a form.  I need people to be able to send json requests to my server.  The json seems to be hitting the server correctly.  I think it has to do with the way rails is using it.

Comment: Use pry and then test if email attribute is present in data you have sent.

Comment: How do you use pry

Comment: Don't you know binding pry, a gem for debugging rails app ? Answer Updated